# Keep web outlook add in always display

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an web outlook add in which extract information from selected email and then save to my database. However I need to select each email and then open the add in to handle my logic, each email I need to reopen the add in. Is there anyway that we can keep the add in always display, and new data is refresh based on selected email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the documentation on how to [implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane). It might help your case.

Comment: This only works in Outlook 2016 ? I can't make it work in Office 365 Outlook